# Execute windows command inside C++ and redirect the output to local string

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I'm trying to execute

```
    which file.exe
```

within c++ and want to redirect the result to a string to make further processes

I've tried system and CreateProcess but this executes command and redirects the results to stdout or a file.

but how do I get this result within a local string ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (popen on Unix).

Comment: Did it start working in GUI-subsystem executables? (It was not)

Comment: Are you sure there were problems? I'm not aware of any.

Comment: See the Note starting with "If used in a Windows program" on your own link to MSDN. I'm sure there were (or are) some *real* problems, I just don't remember them well.

Comment: Ah, I see. So whether this is good advise or not depends on whether the OP wants to create a GUI or console application.

Comment: both were helpful.
I use console app so it's easier to use _popen
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Redirect to a pipe (with `CreateProcess`) and read *your* end of the pipe into a local string.